# Returning copy or reference by method

Tags: c++

It is possible to write a method which can return reference or copy (getMember(bool getCopy)) to class member based on bool argument passed to this method?

```
class Class
{

  const std::vector<int>& getMember() { return _member; }
  const std::vector<int> getCopyOfMember() { return _member; }
  ??? getMember(bool getCopy) { ??? }
  std::vector<int> _member;
}
```

I can use:

```
Class cl;
const std::vector<int>& myVector = isCopyNeeded ?
    cl.getCopyMember() :
    cl.getMember();

for (auto elem : myVector)
   ...
```

Hovewer I want something like this:

```
for (auto elem : cl.getMember(isCopyNeeded))
  ...
```

Comment: No, a function can only have one return type.

Comment: Return types of functions must be known at compile time. You're asking for a return type that is determined at run-time.

Comment: Maybe can I use std::unique_ptr to make universal getter?

Comment: you can use template, but then you couldn't do it on runtime

Comment: If you return by const reference, you will automatically copy it if you assign the return value to a non-reference. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I want to use copy of std::vector when application use more than one thread. In case with one thread I want to use reference.

Comment: You still need to assign the return value to something, and there's no way to make that dynamic too.

Answer (score 9):

A function can only have one return type, so no, it can't be done.
It's also not clear what purpose it coud possibly serve.

Normally, you would provide the function that returns a const reference:

```
const std::vector<int>& getMember() const { return _member; }
```

and then your users can choose if they want a reference:

```
const std::vector<int>& aReference = anObject.getMember();
```

or a copy:

```
std::vector<int> aCopy = anObject.getMember();
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the return type based on the value of an argument. One option is to use two overloaded functions using tag types to differentiate them.

```
 const std::vector<int>& getMember(std::true_type tag) { return _member; }
 std::vector<int> getMember(std::false_type tag) { return _member; }
```

You need to add

```
#include <type_traits>
```

to use `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`.

Of course, you have to call them using a `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` as arguments.

```
Class c;
auto ret1 = c.getNumber(std:::true_type{});
auto ret2 = c.getNumber(std:::false_type{});
```

Comment: And that really selects one of the overloads based on a `true`/`false` constant parameter? That's freakin' magic.

Comment: @MarkRansom, that might be useful some day :)

Comment: @MarkRansom: Look into type traits and tag dispatch. Note that this is all compile-time type deduction.